# Upload variables from C# to MySQL database with server-side connection function

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I have a C# app, that usually, connect to a Mysql server through some functions and upload variables.

When I decompile the app, it shows Mysql connection parameters.

So I thought, that to resolve vulnerabilities problems, I want a server-side program (linux) or a script that receive only variables and update a table.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds confusing to me at least. Do you want something like a stored proc that the client can call with parameters? Do you want your connection to house new User Variables with @ signs sent up?

Comment: I want a php service or a program on the server that simply insert into a sql table some variables from the app client, but application-controlled. @Drew

Comment: you want some c# variables of yours (some Strings and ints and things) inserted via PHP to a mysql table. So, where are you right now? Do you need a chat session in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat or are you really close?

Comment: In addition to the dupe target close, consider the use of SSL / TLS and a layer like [CefSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cefsharp/info) to handle cookies, and therefore PHP "session"